# Convert Char length for MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a comparable function for MySQL that does the same thing as this:

```
convert(CHAR, 'column name', 12) AS 'column name'
```

I'm running into problems joining a field b/c one field has varying lengths, and the other is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I can just use TRIM and it will get me to where I want, go figure.

```
trim(`column name`)
```